# What is the name of the vertex relax algorithm? "slide relax"

Tags: mesh, add-on, vertices, geometry, loop

Is there a relax algorithm that would **slide** vertices from flat areas to sharp ones while maintaining the shape of the loop?

If something like that exists, what is the name of such an addon or algorithm, perhaps there are similar tools in other software?

*please, do not suggest solutions like "make subdivide and then limited dissolve"*

This is necessary to quickly optimize many loops for low poly geometry, the mesh should be preserved.
[image: example of the required result]

Comment: I hope my answer does what you want. I've refinde it a bit if you're not only going to bevel vertices.

Comment: Have you tried the Loop Tools addon? It has a relax function, might be what you are looking for...

Comment: I guess it's not easy without changing the geometry... even when looking at your example image, there you have the problem if you're just sliding the vertices without adding new ones, then the tip of the curve is more relaxed than before, but the longer edges got less relaxed. So relaxation in some parts leads to tension in other parts.

Answer (score 1):

One method to do that:

1. Select all vertices that you want to be smoothed out,
2. hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to Bevel,
3. <kbd>V</kbd> to bevel vertices instead of edges,
4. press <kbd>M</kbd> until mode *Percent* is selected,
5. use the mouse wheel for setting the number of segments you like (an even number let's you keep the original vertices in place, an odd number splits them),
6. drag the mouse to adjust the bevel,
7. hit <kbd>Return</kbd> or press <kbd>LMB</kbd> once you're satisfied with the result.

Of course you can also hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, then <kbd>Return</kbd> or <kbd>LMB</kbd> to edit the values in the *Bevel Properties Menu*.

This description applies to the visualization. If that's a top view of e.g. a wall you'd like to smooth, then you don't have to bevel the vertices, but the corresponding, i.e. you can skip step 3.

Comment: Thanks, but this option doesn't work for me. You cannot change the geometry (this is the difficulty) you just need to move the vertices. The blender does not have the function I want, all types of relax work another. I want to find  something in other software in order to make a blender add-on based on this.

Comment: Alright, I got this wrong... well, I'll leave the answer here, maybe it helps people to don't have to keep the geometry.
I actually have no idea how to help you with a function that Blender has implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'relax' function from `Add-ons->LoopTools`
It will smooth out your polyline without adding new vertices.
'Cubic interpolation' is especially good at keeping the original shape of the curve.